# LOAD DATA INFILE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

When using LOAD DATA INFILE, is there a way to get the same functionality provided by ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE of regular INSERT statements?

What I want to do is: for each line of my file, if the row doesn't exist, a new row is inserted, otherwise the selected fields are updated.

My table has 5 columns: A, B, C, D and E. A is the primary key. Sometimes, I have to insert new rows with all the values, but sometimes I have to update only B and C, for example. But, the point is that I want to regroup all the INSERT or UPDATE in the same file.

Thanks

Comment: could you give the structure of your destination table please? Also, there's something unclear. If the row already exists why would you update it?

Comment: No, you can't. the load statement is for a straightforward "slurp in the whole file". Your only option is a 'replace' parameter to do a full record swap if a loaded row has a primary/unique key conflict with an existing record: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I've edited the question. Concerning existing rows, because I want to update some of their fields but not all.

Comment: @MarcB Replacing the record doesn't help me since I'll loose information present in the fields I don't want to update.

Comment: Then don't use a load infile query - it can't do what you want.

Comment: Hi Mickael, take a look at my answer to this question, it should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253605/import-csv-to-update-only-one-column-in-table/10253773#10253773

Comment: @MarcB Which good alternatives are there? By good, I mean good performance.

Comment: @IkeWalker I've looked at your solution, but I think the UPDATE will take a lot of time. If I'm going to the LOAD DATA INFILE direction, this is because I don't want my threads to block during the INSERT but here they will block during the UPDATE.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache, you can do the updates in smaller chunks if you want, for example using a where clause to specify a range of primary key values on the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert/update some of fields, then you should load data into additional table, and then use INSERT, UPDATE or INSERT...SELECT+ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement to copy/modify data; otherwise other fields will be set to NULL.

The REPLACE option in LOAD DATA INFILE won't help you in this case.

---

Also, you can use [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool (CSV format) in dbForge Studio for MySQL (free express edition), just choose Append/Update import mode and specify fields mapping in the Data Import wizard.

Comment: It depends on data size, indexes. You should test it to answer.