# How do i use an array in an mysqli insert query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm writing a PHP script which is getting .txt from a browsergame-server with comma seperated entrys like this:
table: player

**rows:** `player_id, name, ally_id, villages, points, rank`

**entry:** `22858,Hzombi,4258,9,77636,215`

Its looking for all entries containing the static ally_id and write it to my database. Thats working fine and its writing like 20 entries.

Now i have a second table with Bashpoints which should be written to the DB:
kill_all:

**rows:** `rank,id,points`

**entry:** `314,22858,309969`

Now i want to load all ID's from player table in an array or sth and write all bashpoints from the second .txt file into the DB which mach my player_id.

**Like this:**

1. take the array with the "player_id"-values from table 1
2. write the specific rows from the textfile to table2 which mach
   all entries in "player_id" array.

I hope you understand what i mean. I'm not a php freak and my english is horrible :)

Maybe somone can give me a sample. Thanks

Thats the full code:

```
function write_data_kill_all(){
//Config daten verfügbar machen
 global $conn;
 global $ally_id;
 global $world_id;

  //DB ->player->player_id holen um später zu vergleichen
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select player_id from player");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $player_id = $row['player_id'];
  $array[] = $player_id;
  }

  //Spieldaten laden und entpacken
  $lines = gzfile("http://".$world_id.".die-staemme.de/map/kill_all.txt.gz");
    //DB Tabelle leeren
    mysqli_query($conn, "TRUNCATE TABLE kill_all");

  if(!is_array($lines)){die('Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden');}
                $query =
                "REPLACE INTO kill_all (rank, id, kills)
                VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."')
                WHERE id IN ('".$player_id."')"
                or die(mysqli_error());
                if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
                echo "<p style=\"font-size:11px; font-family:verdana;\">Besiegte Gegner Allgemein wurde erfolgreich eingetragen!</p>\n";
                else
                echo mysql_error();
unset($lines);
unset($line);
//-----function ENDE
}
```

That shows nothing, no echo and no DB entry

Comment: Sounds great. **What have you tried?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV to Update rows in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495600/import-csv-to-update-rows-in-table)

Comment: added the code to start post