# Update MySQL table records using CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, import-from-csv

I'm using MySQL with 5.7.21-21 version, and I have a table `shipping_rate` with structure like this:

```
+---------+----+
|entity_id|rate|
+---------+----+
```

i want to update the record using csv file using MySQL command line, here's what my csv file look like:

[image]

i tried to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21495728/10915710), and modify some code so it will fit my table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_table (entity_id,rate)

LOAD DATA INFILE 'sr.csv' 
INTO TABLE temp_update_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (entity_id, rate); 

UPDATE shipping_rate
INNER JOIN temp_update_table on temp_update_table.entity_id = shipping_rate.entity_id
SET shipping_rate.rate = temp_update_table.rate;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_table;
```

but i always got an error like this:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ' rate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the datatypes for the columns in the `temp_update_table` table.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_update_table (
    entity_id INT,
    rate INT,
    INDEX (entity_id)
);
```

It's also a good idea to add an index on the column used in the join.

Since your CSV file has a header line that should be skipped, you need to use the `IGNORE` clause.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'sr.csv' 
INTO TABLE temp_update_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(entity_id, rate);
```

Comment: it works, but when i select the first record of the temporary table it show enity_id and the rate is 0 [result from select](https://i.imgur.com/MJ7zpkE.png)

Comment: Your CSV file has a header line, so use the `IGNORE 1 LINE` clause in `LOAD DATA INFILE` to skip it.

Comment: got this error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE 1 LINE' at line 1` when i put the `IGNORE 1 LINE` at the end of `LOAD DATA INFILE` the mysql command look like this `LOAD DATA INFILE 'sr.csv' INTO TABLE temp_update_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (entity_id, rate) IGNORE 1 LINE;`

Comment: It's `LINES` not `LINE`. I corrected my answer several minutes ago.

Comment: It has to go before `(entity_id, rate)`.

Comment: ok thats solve the problem, but i got another error looks like this `ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect decimal value: '#N/A' for column 'rate' at row 1`

Comment: You have a row with `#N/A` instead of a rate in the CSV file.

Comment: What is that supposed to do when you try to update the table? If it should be ignored, can you just remove them from the CSV file before uploading? If not, you'll need to change the column to `VARCHAR()`, then filter them out in the `UPDATE`.