# Importing and exporting TSVs with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, csv, mysqlimport

I'm using a database with MySQL 5.7, and sometimes, data needs to be updated using a mixture of scripts and manual editing. Because people working with the database are usually not familiar with SQL, I'd like to export the data as a TSV, which then could be manipulated (for example with Python's `pandas` module) and then be imported back. I assume the standard way would be to directly connect to the database, but using TSVs has some upsides in this situation, I think. I've been reading the MySQL docs and some stackoverflow questions to find the best way to do this. I've found a couple of solutions, however, they all are somewhat inconvenient. I will list them below and explain my problems with them.

**My question is:** did I miss something, for example some helpful SQL commands or CLI options to help with this? Or are the solutions I found already the best when importing/exporting TSVs?

My example database looks like this:

**Database: Export_test**

*Table: Sample*

| Field | Type | Null | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI |
| text_data | text | NO |  |
| optional | int(11) | YES |  |
| time | timestamp | NO |  |

Example data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Sample` VALUES (1,'first line\\\nsecond line',NULL,'2022-02-16 20:17:38');
```

The data contains an escaped newline, which caused a lot of problems for me when exporting.

*Table: Reference*

| Field | Type | Null | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | NO | PRI |
| foreign_key | int(11) | NO | MUL |

Example data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `Reference` VALUES (1,1);
```

`foreign_key` is referencing a `Sample`.`id`.

**Note about encoding**: As a caveat for people trying to do the same thing: If you want to export/import data, make sure that [characters sets and collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html) are set up correctly for connections. This caused me some headache, because although the data itself is `utf8mb4`, the client, server and connection character sets were `latin1`, which caused some loss of data in some instances.

## Export

So, for exporting, I found basically three solutions, and they all behave somewhat differently:

### A: SELECT stdout redirection

```bash
mysql Export_test -e "SELECT * FROM Sample;" > out.tsv
```

Output:

```plaintext
id  text_data   optional    time
1   first line\\\nsecond line   NULL    2022-02-16 21:26:13
```

Pros:

- headers are added, which makes it easy to use with external programs
- formatting works as intended

Cons:

- `NULL` is used for null values; when importing, `\N` is required instead; as far as I know, this can't be configured for exports

Workaround: replace `NULL` values when editing the data

### B: [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

```bash
mysql Export_test -e "SELECT * FROM Sample INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/out.tsv';"
```

Output:

```plaintext
1   first line\\\
second line \N  2022-02-16 21:26:13
```

Pros:

- `\N` is used for null data

Cons:

- escaped linebreaks are not handled correctly
- headers are missing
- file writing permission issues

Workaround: fix linebreaks manually; add headers by hand or supply them in the script; use `/tmp/` as output directory

### C: [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) with `--tab` (performs `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` behind the scenes)

```bash
mysqldump --tab='/tmp/' --skip-tz-utc Export_test Sample
```

Output, pros and cons: same as export variant B

Something that should be noted: the output is only the same as B, if `--skip-tz-utc` is used; otherwise, timestamps will be converted to UTC, and will be off after importing the data.

## Import

Something I didn't realize it first, is that it's impossible to merely update data directly with [LOAD INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) or [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html), although that's something many GUI tools appear to be doing and [other people attempted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495600/import-csv-to-update-rows-in-table). For me as an beginner, this wasn't immediately clear from the MySQL docs. A workaround appears to be creating an empty table, import the data there and then updating the actual table of interest via a join. I also thought one could update individual columns with this, which again is not possible. If there are some other ways to achieve this, I would really like to know.

As far as I could tell, there are two options, which do pretty much the same thing:

**LOAD INTO**:

```bash
mysql Export_test -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/Sample.tsv' REPLACE INTO TABLE Sample IGNORE 1 LINES; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"
```

**mysqlimport** (performs `LOAD INTO` behind the scenes):

```bash
mysqlimport --replace Export_test /tmp/Sample.tsv
```

Notice: if there are foreign key constraints like in this example, `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` needs to be performed (as far as I can tell, `mysqlimport` can't be directly used in these cases). Also, `IGNORE 1 LINES` or `--ignore-lines` can be used to skip the first line if the input TSV contains a header. For `mysqlimport`, the name of the input file without extension must be the name of the table. Again, file reading permissions can be an issue, and `/tmp/` is used to avoid that.

**Are there ways to make this process more convenient?** Like, are there some options I can use to avoid the manual workarounds, or are there ways to use TSV importing to `UPDATE` entries without creating a temporary table?

What I ended up doing was using `LOAD INTO OUTFILE` for exporting, added a header manually and also fixed the malformed lines by hand. After manipulating the data, I used `LOAD DATA INTO` to update the data. In another case, I exported with `SELECT` to stdout redirection, manipulated the data and then added a script, which just created a file with a bunch of `UPDATE ... WHERE` statements with the corresponding data. Then I ran the resulting `.sql` in my database. Is the latter maybe the best option in this case?

Comment: have you an doppel quotes in your data?

Comment: I do, but luckily I did not encounter escaping/quoting problems

Comment: then look for another charackter that can be used for enclosing fields for example `¬` anything that usually doesn't exist in your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting and importing is indeed sort of clunky in MySQL.

One problem is that it introduces a race condition. What if you export data to work on it, then someone modifies the data in the database, then you import your modified data, overwriting your friend's recent changes?

If you say, "no one is allowed to change data until you re-import the data," that could cause an unacceptably long time where clients are blocked, if the table is large.

The trend is that people want the database to minimize downtime, and ideally to have no downtime at all. Advancements in database tools are generally made with this priority in mind, not so much to accommodate your workflow of taking the data out of MySQL for transformations.

Also what if the database is large enough that the exported data causes a problem because where do you store a 500GB TSV file? Does pandas even work on such a large file?

What most people do is modify data while it remains in the database. They use in-place UPDATE statements to modify data. If they can't do this in one pass (there's a practical limit of 4GB for a binary log event, for example), then they UPDATE more modest-size subsets of rows, looping until they have transformed the data on all rows of a given table.

Comment: I expected that this was the standard way. However, in our (fairly small) database with a lot of "static" data and only internal writing accesses (where race conditions and downtime aren't a big problem), we have a lot of "wild", unstructured data. Accordingly, it is very convenient for us to export tables, because people are familiar with them, and it makes it easier to see the data and to make some manual changes, if necessary. This way, we don't have to setup database access or local databases for people to work with, either. I just expected this would be fairly straight forward task

Comment: Sounds like you could just leave it in the TSV file. Why do you need to store it in MySQL at all, if it's fairly small and unstructured?

Comment: Oh, it still has a web interface with a lot of reading accesses. But writes are rare and mostly performed by members of our team, and some parts of the data aren't even editable via the web interface currently. I'm sorry that I didn't make this clear. I guess it's a fairly niche application, but I really think working with exported tables is a tolerable solution in this case. I've found that quite some people tried working eith databases like that, with differing solutions, so maybe this question could at least give an overview over some approaches and potential problems

Comment: A web application can work with TSV data directly. It doesn't necessarily have to use an SQL database.

Comment: I see. Well, I'm not in the position to change the database architecture. I'm assuming the decision was made to use a SQL database because the data consists of several complex tables and relationships, SQL offers capabilities like triggers, and offers wide compatibility with ORMs, which are used. I would have also thought an SQL database would be more performant, and that it would be easier to maintain one SQL database instead of multiple TSVs. But judging from your comment I assume all of the above things could be handled by some TSV based system as well. But again, I can't really change it

Comment: Well, then I'm not sure why you asked your question to begin with. You are committed to using an SQL database, and you are committed to periodic export and import of data to update it, instead of updating in the database. You're not open to any changes to either of these aspects. You have already learned about the methods for exporting and importing data in MySQL, which are admittedly pretty awkward. What else were you expecting as an answer?

Comment: I'm really sorry. Your reply DID answer my question, and I am thankful for your advice. Sorry, I think I just got caught up justifying why I would do such a thing in the first place. Your answer was basically "exporting/importing like this is indeed inconvenient, and SQL databases aren't intended to be used like that, for good reasons", right? You are definitely right, and I will accept this answer. But what I had also hoped for was people chiming in with, "yes, it is inconvenient, what I do to avoid these problems is..." or "you missed this helpful CLI option", if I wanted to stick with it

Comment: Fair enough. Sometimes there is an obscure CLI tool that people forget. Or a community add-on tool that is indispensable. But in this case, know that nearly everyone favors doing updates in the database without export & import, because of the race condition I mentioned early in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have accepted this answer as the correct one, as there's probably not much left to improve this specific process, just like you said.