# Special Characters handling in DB after converting to UTF 8

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I am currently facing an issues, my site has users from across the globe and they use special characters in their addresses, i have converted my DB to handle the new users addresses, but the addresses which were there earlier in the database are not coming across readable format when i export the addresses to CSV. Is there any script which can clean up the characters saved when the DB was in Latin -1 to how they should originally appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a one-off change:

1. Restore a backup of your database from before your changes to your
   development environment.
2. Export the name and address tables to CSV.
3. Read the CSV into a normal spreadsheet with OpenOffice, specifying source encoding.
4. Check all is okay, save as .ods spreadsheet
5. Reopen, save as CSV, specify UTF-8
6. Create temporary table in new database with UTF-8 encoding
7. Update the rows as outlined here:

[Import CSV to Update only one column in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253605/import-csv-to-update-only-one-column-in-table)