# How to import csv file to specific column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I experienced a case when I forgot to input data in the last column, do I have to overwrite the data that I previously inputed or can I import the CSV file to a particular column on MySQL?

Comment: How would you know which row to update?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to phpMyAdmin, you could export the information you have now, update the CSV file and re-import the data, overwriting your old records.

Alternatively, have a look at this previously answered question. [Import CSV to Update only one column in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253605/import-csv-to-update-only-one-column-in-table)